# Need to integrate my MVC4 web application with Microsoft Graph SDKs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, microsoft-graph-api

Need to integrate my MVC4 web application with Microsoft Graph SDKs? I am facing version issue. Is there any way to resolve this. I need to integrate my MVC4 web application with MS Teams.

Comment: What issue do you have? Could you share more details, exceptions?

Comment: yeah share the detailed info... in case if there is error related with Microsoft Graph API (timestamp, requestid) as well.